# How to add magnitude or value to a vector in Python?

Tags: numpy, linear-algebra, word2vec

I am using this function to calculate distance between 2 vectors a,b, of size 300, word2vec, I get the distance between 'hot' and 'cold' to be equal 1.

How to add this value (1) to a vector, becz i thought simply new_vec=model['hot']+1, but when I do the calc dist(new_vec,model['hot'])=17?

```
import numpy
def dist(a,b):
  return numpy.linalg.norm(a-b)


a=model['hot']
c=a+1
dist(a,c)

17
```

I expected dist(a,c) will give me back 1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should review what the [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)) is. In the case of numpy, the default is to use the L-2 norm (a.k.a the Euclidean norm). When you add 1 to a vector, the call is to add 1 to all of the elements in the vector.

```
>> vec1 = np.random.normal(0,1,size=300)
>> print(vec1[:5])
... [ 1.18469795  0.04074346 -1.77579852  0.23806222  0.81620881]

>> vec2 = vec1 + 1
>> print(vec2[:5])
... [ 2.18469795  1.04074346 -0.77579852  1.23806222  1.81620881]
```

Now, your call to `norm` is saying `sqrt( (a1-b1)**2 + (a2-b2)**2 + ... + (aN-bN)**2 )` where `N` is the length of the vector and `a` is the first vector and `b` is the second vector *(and ai being the ith element in a)*. Since `(a1-b1)**2 == (a2-b2)**2 == ... == (aN-bN)**2 == 1` we expect this sum to produce N which in your case is 300. So `sqrt(300) = 17.3` is the expected answer.

```
>> print(np.linalg.norm(vec1-vec2))
... 17.320508075688775
```

To answer the question, "How to add a value to a vector": you have done this correctly. If you'd like to add a value to a specific element then you can do `vec2[ix] += value` where `ix` indexes the element that you wish to add. If you want to add a value uniformly across all elements in the vector that will change the norm by 1, then add `np.sqrt(1/300)`.

Also possibly relevant is a more commonly used distance metric for word2vec vectors: the [cosine distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) which measures the angle between two vectors.

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanation, if I can ask further, since you mentioned cosine_sim, so if cos_sim('cold','hot')=0.7, how do i add this magnitude to a vector? as in new_vec=model['hot']+(0.7)

Comment: It's not typical in this domain to "add this magnitude to a vector", so it'd probably help to see more of **why** you want to do that. (If you want to make the vector "point in the same direction, but more strongly", it'd be more typical to multiply the vector by some factor. But as word-vector to word-vector comparisons are typically done by cosine-similarity, which is by definition **not** affected by vectors' magnitude, that would again be an atypical operation.)